# popup is not working while using remote in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement pagination in my project using the remote option. It is rendering the target file successfully but is failing to display the popup. I think escape_javascipt code in output.js.erb file is preventing the display the popup. Code in the output.js.erb is given below

```
$("#output").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'output') %>")
```

The below code is used for pagination in the view file

```
= link_to "Show more ouputs", :page=>(@page+1).to_s, :remote => true
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think something is wrong with the `= link_to "Show more ouputs", :page=>(@page+1).to_s, :remote => true`, path missing?

Comment: I am getting the response and the result is also rendered. But the issue is only for the popup. I think javascript is not working

Comment: please show your controller action

Comment: and while you are at it: the partial `output` as well

Answer (score 0):

If your popup requires javascript and you trying to add it with `append()` you should try to do something like this

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = "alert('replace alert with javascript for your popup');"
$("#output").append( script );
```

I think, it will be better if you append html with `$("#output").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'output') %>")` and place javascript for modal to output.js.erb